# GXT - Truncated text in a Window

Tags: java, gxt

I've a Window which contains two ContentPanel (horizontally), one with a Image into it and the other one with some text. The problem is that my text is truncated : it's going out of the Window...

```
Window win = new Window();
win.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
win.setMinWidth( 250 );
win.setHeight( 120 );

ContentPanel content = new ContentPanel( new RowLayout( Orientation.HORIZONTAL ) );
ContentPanel iconePanel = new ContentPanel( new FillLayout() );
iconePanel.add(myImage);
content.add( iconePanel, new RowData( 48, 1 ) );

Text textPanel = new Text();
textPanel.setText( msg );
content.add( textPanel, new RowData( -1, 1 ) );
win.add( content );
win.show();
```

How can I keep the text in the panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its necessary that you should have a good understanding of different panels in the  GXT,There is another trick by adjusting the padding size,Its better you use a **firebug** and adjust the Layout using Firebug,it will help a lot for adjusting the window.

Comment: I tried (using Chrome's Developper Tools), but, first, there's some problems. The div which contains the two others div (image + text) is shorter than the text's div. And when I tried to add a padding to the text, it had no effect. I'll try with FitLayout instead of FillLayout

Comment: Nope, didn't work either.
EDIT : Just noticed, when i disabled the Width, it works perfectly. Now I just have to find out how to do the same with Java.

Comment: Okay...that's good.Hope you got the problem solved.Also please check with all the browsers,backward compatibility too.

Comment: It works perfectly. Just have to add `textPanel.setAutoWidth( true )` and it works. Try with IE9 (compatibility mode and without), Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Thanks to @Prabhath for big help :)